# Simple python script to build in Jenkins using ubuntu 22.04.2

Tags: command-line, python, jenkins

I have created a simple python file project.py on my desktop in ubuntu 22.04.2

I tried to build a simple free project on Jenkins and in the execution shell I wrote the location of the python file then apply and saved it.

When building it showed failure.
What is the reason and what should I write in the execution shell.

I have given the required file permission with chmod 777

Error msg-

python3 : can't open file

Build step Execution shell mark build as failure